# intellij - ultimate version jsp highlighting

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I am doing some JSP development on Intellij IDEA 2017.2 and have some issues with syntax highlighting/jsp page parsing.
[image: out.println error]

it shows that it cannot resolve a method, however, the JSP page is deployed on Elastic Beanstalk and works just fine.

Comment: Do you have Java EE dependency added to project?

Comment: @y.bedrov - noticed last night that I created a regular Java project, not the Java EE project. This seemed to have been an issue.